# ADD MAVEN_OPTS Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to package a project using native-image-maven-plugin from GraalVM. I don't want to install native-image-tool, and I receiving the following error: 
`Image building on Java 11+ without native-image requires MAVEN_OPTS='--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.module=ALL-UNNAMED'`

I've tried different ways to add these options but keep getting the same error. I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to add these options to the embedded Maven from Intellij.

Thanks in advance

Comment: VM options for maven server can be configured in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | VM options" .

Comment: I did it like that but doesn't worked for me. I'm getting the same error message.

Comment: Please attach screenshot from "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | VM options" with configured options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error working from the command line on windows 10. The only way to get one step further was to definitively install the native-image extension with `gu install native-image` and then copy `<GRAAVM_HOME>\lib\svm\bin\native-image.exe` to `<GRAAVM_HOME>\bin` as suggested here: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2151#issuecomment-647522072